# Removing a redundant dictionary from a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, redundancy

Lets say I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'county': 'Lincoln County', 'state': 'SD', 'fips': '46083'}, {'county': 'Minnehaha County', 'state': 'SD', 'fips': '46099'}, {'county': 'Minnehaha County', 'state': 'SD', 'fips': '46099'},...]
```

In the above example, 2 of the dictionaries in this list are the same. What I want to do is check and see, by the `fips` key if the value. I know that I can use something like this to check in a dictionary, and in essence, create a new list of only unique entries:

```
result = {}

for key,value in dictionary.items():
    if value not in result.values():
        result[key] = value

print result
```

But I am having difficulty apply this to a ***list*** of dictionaries. What am I doing wrong here?

```
for i in dictionary:
    for key,value in dictionary[i].items():
        if value not in result.values():
            result[key] = value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a check flag.

**Ex:**

```
d = [{'county': 'Lincoln County', 'state': 'SD', 'fips': '46083'}, {'county': 'Minnehaha County', 'state': 'SD', 'fips': '46099'}, {'county': 'Minnehaha County', 'state': 'SD', 'fips': '46099'}]

check_val  = set()
res = []
for i in d:
    if i["fips"] not in check_val:
        res.append(i)
        check_val.add(i["fips"])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'county': 'Lincoln County', 'state': 'SD', 'fips': '46083'}, {'county': 'Minnehaha County', 'state': 'SD', 'fips': '46099'}]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and was super easy to implement!

Comment: You are welcome :)